# How can I get file field url in drupal 7 from views of its content type?

Tags: 7, theming, files

It has been a few days I'm trying to get the uploaded file urls in drupal7 (using default file filed in drupal content type) from a view. I must get this url in page which a view is embedded inside it, this view shows 10 items of its content type per page, how can I get the url of filefield?

should I use preprocess function or any thing else?

I have tried many ways suggested in many websites but I have failed. is there any straight forward solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the Formatter of file to `URL to file` in views administrative menu and then by this code `strip_tags($fields['field_file']->content);` you will get the url

Comment: This is right. But in order for the 'URL to file' option to appear, you must enable the image_url_formatter module (https://drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter)

Comment: @Druvision I didnt enable this module and it still working

Comment: In the end I did enable this module and it's still not working. Too many modules.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really clear what you mean by 'access' in this context, but if you're looking to get the details for a file uploaded through a file field:

```
$node = node_load(1);
if ( ($field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_file')) ) {
  $file = file_load($field_items[0]['fid']);

  $uri = $file->uri;
  $external_url = file_create_url($uri);
}
```

Or to grab the external URL directly with an `EntityMetadataWrapper`:

```
$node = node_load(1);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$external_url = $wrapper->field_files[0]->file->url->value();
```

Comment: where should I use this code?

Comment: Wherever you want/need to use it, there's no specific place for it to go

Comment: can I use it in views-view-field template function ?

Comment: Well don't put it in the template file (it'll cause havoc with caching), but in a preprocess function, sure

Comment: what if I don't use node page? I mean I'm trying to get file url in a page which a view is embedded inside it. this view shows 10 items of a certain content type which has file field. then in what preprocess function I must use it?

Comment: Sorry you've lost me, I don't understand what you mean. Your question doesn't mention views at all

Comment: So I edit it, Im trying to get it in views

Comment: Still haven't got a clue what you mean, sorry. As this answers the original question I'll leave it here, might be useful for a future visitor. Please don't edit the question any further, if you need to significantly change the scope of what you're asking, just ask a new question. Thanks

Comment: This is part of my project and I must complete it as soon as possible. the question is clear: I have a content type and one of its fields is File. I created a view of this content type that shows 10 items per page. this view shows some of the fields and one of them is Filefields. now I need to get the filefields url, that's all. thanks for your attention

Comment: I'm afraid your deadlines are irrelevant here - this is a Q+A site, the mission is to build a site full of high quality content, not to do people's job for them within a certain time constraint. I disagree that your question is clear; I can't understand it, and I've been developing in Drupal for over 3 years and speaking English for over 30. You haven't describe the context in which you need to 'get' the value, what you need to do with it, or shown that you've made any effort to solve the problem yourself. I'd advise improving the question considerably, but that is your prerogative, of course.

Comment: I changed the formatter of file to `URL to file` in views administrative menu and then by this code ` strip_tags($fields['field_file']->content);` I got the url.

Comment: From a module I was able to use it but I had to change this line `$external_url = $wrapper->field_files[0]->file->url->value();` to  `$external_url = $wrapper->field_files->file->url->value();`